# Why is there a difference between using a list or a string with subprocess.Popen and quotes on the commandline

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, quotes, popen

When running the following script:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print sys.argv[1]
    sys.exit(0)

commandline = [sys.executable]
commandline.append(os.path.realpath(__file__))
commandline.append('"test"')

p = subprocess.Popen(commandline)
p.wait()

p = subprocess.Popen(" ".join(commandline))
p.wait()
```

It returns the following output

```
"test"
test
```

Why is there a difference between providing a list of arguments or one string?
This is run on a windows machine and you will see backslashes before the quotes on the command in the task manager.

I expected the same result in both runs.

Edit:

The problem is not so much in the automatic escaping of spaces (I find that is the programmers responsibility), but more about my quotes being escaped or not in the process commandline.

These are the two subprocesses taken from the windows task manager:

[image: Task manager escaping quotes]

A different non-python process parses the first commandline with the backslashes, which brings unexpected behaviour. How can I have it so that I can use a list and not have the quotes escaped on the commandline?

Edit2:

The quotes are definitely added by python. If you run the following:

```
import subprocess

commandline = ['echo']
commandline.append('"test"')
commandline.append('>')
commandline.append(r'D:\test1.txt')

p = subprocess.Popen(commandline, shell=True)
p.wait()

commandline = 'echo "test" > D:\\test2.txt'
p = subprocess.Popen(commandline, shell=True)
p.wait()
```

Then you will see that the outputs are

D:\test1.txt:

```
\"test\"
```

D:\test2.txt:

```
"test"
```

Answer (score 0):

The string API is dangerous since it might change the meaning of arguments. Example: You want to execute `C:\Program Files\App\app.exe`. If you use the string version of `Popen()`, you get an error:

```
C:\Program: Error 13
```

What happens is that with the string API, Python will split the input by spaces and try to start the command `C:\Program` with the single argument `Files\App\app.exe`. To fix this, you need to quote properly. Which gets you in quote hell when you have quotes in your arguments (i.e. when you really want to pass `"test"` as an argument *with* the quotes).

To solve this (and other subtle) bugs, there is the list API where each element of the list will become a single item passed to the OS without any modifications. With list API, you get what you see. If you quote an argument with the list API, it will be passed on with the quotes. If there are spaces, they won't split your argument. If there are arbitrary other special characters (like `*` or `%`), they will all be passed on.

**[EDIT]** As usual, things are much more complex on Windows. [From the Python documentation for the `subprocess` module](https://python.readthedocs.org/en/v2.7.2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows):

> 17.1.5.1. Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows
>
> On Windows, an args sequence is converted to a string that can be parsed using the following rules (which correspond to the rules used by the MS C runtime):
>
> 1. Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a tab.
> 2. A string surrounded by double quotation marks is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted string can be embedded in an argument.
> 3. A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash is interpreted as a literal double quotation mark.
> 4. Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they immediately precede a double quotation mark.
> 5. If backslashes immediately precede a double quotation mark, every pair of backslashes is interpreted as a literal backslash. If the number of backslashes is odd, the last backslash escapes the next double quotation mark as described in rule 3.

So the backslashes are there because MS C runtime wants it that way.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I edited my question to specify the actual problem more clearly.

Comment: To not have quotes, you must omit them when adding the element to the list.

Comment: But I do want quotes. I just don't want them with slashes before them when the subprocess is launched. Look at the image I provided. The second line is using 1 string as input for Popen and it has the quotes correctly set. The first line is using the list as input to Popen and that one has backslashes before it, which is wrong. According to your logic I believe the other arguments should have gotten quote's around them as well which they don't.

Comment: Python doesn't ass backslashes. It passes the list to your OS. My first guess would be that the task manager adds those. More importantly: Why do you want quotes anyway? Maybe there is a much better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. I've edited my question again and added a new code sample.

The reason why I need quotes is because the external program parses the arguments like that: app.exe -something -value="bla123"
Where the quotes are mandatory.

Comment: I would expect `['app.exe', '-something', '-value="bla123"']` to work in this case. Can you try with Python 3 just to see whether that behaves differently? Also, try a command line tool or the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see whether they show a different output when you list the processes arguments.

Comment: Yeah I did as well, but the application failed. That's why I put up this question. Not to find a fix, as I found a workaround, but to figure out why this happens. It seems incorrect to me.

I'll try python 3, but it's kind of irrelevant though.

Comment: Python 3 does the same thing. Process explorer also shows the backslashes when using a list of arguments and no backslashes when using a string. I'm really sure that python is the culprit here ;)

Comment: It doesn't add the backslashes on Linux. My guess would be that the Windows API adds them but that also doesn't make sense since `\\ ` isn't an escape symbol on Windows. For that reason, it also doesn't make sense for Python to add them since they won't have an effect. So I think what happens is that the tools which show the process list add them but they aren't really there (`app.exe` won't see them, for example)

Comment: PS: That should be a single backslash but Markdown messed with it.

Comment: So why are there backslashes in my files then?

Comment: Turns out you're right but it's not a bug. See my edits.

Comment: Yes I also read that, but then why wouldn't it also escape quotes for Popen's with strings? Or how could I then have non-escaped quotes in lists feeded to Popen. This just seems wrong to me..

Comment: My guess this is one of the places where Unix and Windows are subtly different. On Unix, if you pass a string to `Popen()`, you must also set `shell=True` to enable standard shell processing of the string (= as if you had typed it on the command line). See https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments For this reason, Python can't change the string in any way. I don't see why it would make sense to escape arguments of the list API; you'll have to ask Microsoft.

Comment: It's still python that formats it that way, because it thinks that that is how microsoft want's it. But never mind. I already had a fix before asking this question, I just would've liked some clarification for this inconsistency. Thanks!